# Adding string resource to detail part of Master/Detail template

Tags: java, android, master-detail, getresource

I can't seem to find a good answer here or elsewhere for this, so here goes. I created a Master/Detail android application, so there are two packages is `src`:

```
com.example.app
ItemDetailActivity.java
ItemDetailFragment.java
ItemListActivity.java
ItemListFragment.java

com.example.app.content
ItemContent.java
```

Now, what I want to do is add a formatted string from a resource in `src/res/values/string.xml` to the `ItemContent.java` file. The `strings.xml` file already contains the contact_information string. When I use this line:

```
public CharSequence contact_information = getResources().getText(R.string.contact_information);
```

I get the Eclipse error that `The method getResources() is undefined for the type ItemContent`. When I use the same line in say, `ItemDetailFragment.java` it's fine. What am I missing in the content package to allow me to reference the string?

Comment: Also, rather than using `getResources().getText(int resourceId)` you can just use `getString(int resourceId)` which is a convenience method to avoid the long-winded one you're using

Comment: @SDJMcHattie, would your method still preserve all of my formatting though? That part is crucial to my project.

Comment: What formatting do you mean?  Are you talking about %s and %d that will have a string and a decimal value substituted like `String.format()`?  If so, you can use `getString()` on a `Context` object and you can pass the substitutions in as well all in one, like:  `getString(R.string.contact_information, "First name", "Last name")` where `R.string.contact_information` is a `String` of `"Dear %s %s"`

Comment: @SDJMcHattie I care about HTML elements like <b> <i> <u>

Answer (score 2):

The `getResources()` method is a `Context` method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

If `ItemContent` is not extending `Context` or one of its subclasses, it will not have the `getResources()` method. One way of getting around this is passing a `context` reference to your `ItemContent` or calls made to it that require the `context`.

Edit: Or, as @desseim suggests in the comments, pass in the `Resources` object obtained via `getResources()` to the method that requires it to avoid the possibility of unintentionally leaking the `Context`.

A couple of examples:

```
// If you need the context for other things. If you don't keep the Context around as a 
// class or instance variable, there should be no leaks.
public void foo(Context context){
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    // other code
}
```

Call it from your Activity as:

```
ItemContent itemContent = new ItemContent();
itemContent.foo(SomeActivity.this);
```

Or, with resources:

```
public void bar(Resources res){
    String str = res.getString(R.somestring);
}
```

Call it from your Activity as:

```
ItemContent itemContent = new ItemContent();
itemContent.bar(getResources());
```

Comment: Or even better, pass it directly a `Resources` object (obtained through `getResources()` by the caller for example). It avoids unnecessarily leaking a `Context`.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, it would be optimal to avoid context leaks, but how exactly would I go about doing this direct Resource passing? Could you provide a clearer example?

Comment: Added some clarification.

Comment: After adding the bar method from you example to my ItemContent.java file, the code inside of which is: String str = bar.getString(R.string.contact_information); The contact_information is throwing an error stating that "contact_information cannot be resolved or is not a field." I may have misunderstood your example, really shows how new I am to android!

Comment: The goal is to access my res/values/strings.xml file in ItemContent so that I can use the contact_information string.

Comment: If you added the bar method from my example, the code inside it should be `String str = res.getString(R.string.contact_information);` and you should be calling bar(getResources()). Have you defined the contact_information string in the strings.xml resource file?

Comment: Yes, here is the line from strings.xml: `<string name="contact_information">TODO: Contact Information</string>` I have the method exactly as you do: `public void bar(Resources res){
  String str = res.getString(R.string.contact_information);
 }` it just isn't seeing that string resource at all. If I call the same string in say `ItemDetailFragment` from `com.example.app` package it works, just not in the `ItemContent` inside the `com.example.app.content` package. That was why I think it has to do with the packages or something.

Comment: It shouldn't be a packages issue if you're importing R properly. Try cleaning your project, too.

Comment: Cleaning doesn't help, still can't get this to work. I recently bought an Android book, so if no one can come up with a solution I should be able to figure it out on my own eventually. What is the proper way to import R in this case? I have `import andoid.R;` which throws a warning that I should use the fully qualified version.

Comment: There's your problem. You don't want `android.R`, you want your own `R` to be imported. Something like `com.yourpackagename.R`.